# WCF calling Third party Web Service

Tags: wcf, esb, wcf-web-api

I have a workflow of a payment within a third party.

[image]

Because in POS we don't have a way so that the third party could send the response after the user paid in is phone I thought that I could act in the middle of the POS and the third party (red line on the image).

Then we have a another method that the user could check from time to time to see if the response of that exactly request has already an answer.

Can anyone advise me which is the best way to accomplish this? ESB could be used here? Maybe a WebAPI with a logger.